# how to efficiently catch errors when working with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, try-catch

I'm looking for a way to catch errors without using the classic try catch because this code doesn't work on my SQL version (2005)

```
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1/0;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;
END CATCH;
```

ERROR:

```
Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'TRY'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
```

any workaround? or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Only a comment but SQL Express 2012 is free.

Comment: :) OK but i have 10+ DBs and i do not want to get into any upgrade adventures...yet.

Comment: I think try/catch is supported in 2005... do you have it set to run at a lower compatibility level?

Comment: new to sql server admin...do not really know what is the compatibility lkevel

Comment: [Please read this](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRY
   Try Statement 1
   Try Statement 2
   ...
   Try Statement M
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   Catch Statement 1
   Catch Statement 2
   ...
   Catch Statement N
END CATCH
```

is standard try..catch syntax. And it is supported in 2005 version. See [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/11/sql-server-2005-explanation-of-trycatch-and-error-handling/) for details.

Comment: it is not different from the one i posted, can you explain why it may not work in 2005? a setting ?

Comment: Query seems fine. Error may be outside the try...catch block. Can you post complete query?

Comment: :) there's nothing outside the try catch, if i run my example i get the error posted

Comment: Please confirm and post the version of your RDBMS. Can you post the result of SELECT @@VERSION ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are set for a lower cpmapitbility level and cannot change it without breaking something, then the old way we trapped errors was

```
DECLARE @Error INT 
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(500)


SET @Error = 0  
SET @ErrorMessage = ''
BEGIN TRAN
IF @Error = 0 
   BEGIN
      Do something
      SET @Error = @@Error         
   END

IF @Error = 0 
   BEGIN
      Do something else
      SET @Error = @@Error         
   END

 --this code must be the last code in the proc or batch
IF @Error = 0
   BEGIN    
      COMMIT TRAN
   END 
ELSE
   BEGIN    
      ROLLBACK TRAN
   END
```

The critcal thing is you have to check for an error after every single action you take. No doing it once for three grouped steps for instance.